# Computer hangs up after X screen locking

Tags: linux, arch-linux, intel-graphics

I'm facing the following problem. Computer hangs up after either of those events:

1. After some inactivity time, when the display goes to sleep according "display power management" settings.
2. After I manually lock my X session with `lightdm-lock-command --lock`, `gdmflexiserver` or `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` **twice**. The first time it works and I'm able to return to my session, the second time it hangs up.
3. After I manually lock my X session with either tool (once) and switch to a different tty and back.

In either of those cases, monitor is showing a black screen, there is no reaction on key presses and even on short presses on the power button. The only thing that works is `Alt SysRq REISUB`.

More details about my installation:

- A fresh `ArchLinux` system, working otherwise good
- `gdm`+`gnome` or `lightdm`+`xfce` (reproducible in both cases)
- `xf86-video-intel` video driver

I also tested these commands, and they work: `systemctl susped` (put computer to sleep), `xset dpms force off` (force display power manager to shut down display), `xset dpms force standby`, `xset dpms force suspend`.

UPDATE: I found the following errors in `dmesg`:

```
[   12.599366] [drm:intel_set_pch_fifo_underrun_reporting [i915]] *ERROR* uncleared pch fifo underrun on pch transcoder A
[   12.599398] [drm:intel_pch_fifo_underrun_irq_handler [i915]] *ERROR* PCH transcoder A FIFO underrun
```

UPDATED2: Downgrading to `linux-lts` kernel fixes the problem. The reasons are still unknown (see the answer below).

Answer (score 0):

Installing Linux-LTS "fixes" the problem (`linux-lts` package). Note that this is a work-around, not a real solution to the problem.

Please post your own solution if you have anything better.

Comment: Credits to "Namarrgon" from #archlinux IRC channel on freenode.